# Nagios Core 4.4.3 | Notification configurations

Tags: nagios

Almost I have done all the configuration. But, I've stuck in Notification configurations. I have checked many tutorials and configured `commands.cfg`, `contacts.cfg`. But, after all my notification configurations when I tried restart the NagiOS it throwing error. I don't know where I'm missing configuration.

Please fine below configurations I have done in my Nagios server. Kindly correct me wherever I'm wrong.

**Contact.cfg**

```
define contact {

    contact_name                       sidbiz             
    use                                sidbiz-contact         
    alias                              notisidd            
    email                              mymailid@gymail.com
}

define contactgroup {

    contactgroup_name       siddadmins
    alias                   Sid Notifictions
    members                 sidbiz
}
```

**commands.cfg**

```
#Sidd email notifications

define command {

    command_name    notify-host-email-sidd     // this will referd by contact.cfg
    command_line    /usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** Nagios *****\n\nNotification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\nHost: $HOSTNAME$\nState: $HOSTSTATE$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nInfo: $HOSTOUTPUT$\n\nDate/Time: $LONGDATETIME$\n" | /usr/bin/mail -s "** $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ Host Alert: $HOSTNAME$ is $HOSTSTATE$ **" $CONTACTEMAIL$
}

define command {

    command_name    notify-service-email-sidd  // this will referd by contact.cfg
    command_line    /usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** Nagios *****\n\nNotification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\n\nService: $SERVICEDESC$\nHost: $HOSTALIAS$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nState: $SERVICESTATE$\n\nDate/Time: $LONGDATETIME$\n\nAdditional Info:\n\n$SERVICEOUTPUT$\n" | /usr/bin/mail -s "** $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ Service Alert: $HOSTALIAS$/$SERVICEDESC$ is $SERVICESTATE$ **" $CONTACTEMAIL$
}

Sidd SMS notifications

define command {

    command_name    notify-host-sms-sidd      // this will referd by contact.cfg
    command_line    /usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** Nagios *****\n\nNotification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\nHost: $HOSTNAME$\nState: $HOSTSTATE$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nInfo: $HOSTOUTPUT$\n\nDate/Time: $LONGDATETIME$\n" |wget "http:our.sms.api.url?msisdn=<my-number>&message='** $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ Host Alert: $HOSTNAME$ is $HOSTSTATE$ at: $LONGDATETIME$ **'"
}

define command {

    command_name    notify-service-sms-sidd   // this will referd by contact.cfg
    command_line    /usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** Nagios *****\n\nNotification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\n\nService: $SERVICEDESC$\nHost: $HOSTALIAS$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nState: $SERVICESTATE$\n\nDate/Time: $LONGDATETIME$\n\nAdditional Info:\n\n$SERVICEOUTPUT$\n" |wget "http:our.sms.api.url?msisdn=<my-number>&message='** $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ Service Alert: $HOSTALIAS$/$SERVICEDESC$ is $SERVICESTATE$ at: $LONGDATETIME$ **"
}
```

**templates.cfg**

```
#contact for Sidd
define contact {

    name                            sidbiz-contact
    service_notification_period     24x7
    host_notification_period        24x7
    service_notification_options    c,r
    host_notification_options       d,r
    service_notification_commands   notify-service-sms-sidd,   notify-service-email-sidd
    host_notification_commands      notify-host-sms-sidd,      notify-host-email-sidd
    register                        0
}

# Sidd's Accounts

define host {

    name                            sidd_accounts         
    use                             generic-host            
    check_period                    24x7                    
    check_interval                  2                       
    retry_interval                  1                      
    max_check_attempts              100                   
    check_command                   check-host-alive      
    notification_period             24x7                    
    notification_interval           30                     
    notification_options            d,r                     
    contact_groups                  siddadmins                  
    hostgroups                      sidd_accounts         
    register                        0                      
}
```

**nagios.cfg**

```
cfg_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/commands.cfg
cfg_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/contacts.cfg
cfg_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/timeperiods.cfg
cfg_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/templates.cfg
cfg_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/windows.cfg
cfg_file=/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/linux.cfg
```

**Error output**

```
[root@testing objects]# systemctl restart nagios.service
Job for nagios.service failed because the control process exited with error code.                                                                                       See "systemctl status nagios.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

[root@testing objects]# /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -v /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagi                                                                                      os.cfg

Checking objects...
        Checked 883 services.
        Checked 56 hosts.
        Checked 17 host groups.
        Checked 0 service groups.
Error: Service notification command 'notify-service-email-sidd' specified for contact 'sidbiz' is not defined anywhere!
Error: Service notification command 'notify-service-sms-sidd' specified for contact 'sidbiz' is not defined anywhere!
Error: Host notification command 'notify-host-email-sidd' specified for contact 'sidbiz' is not defined anywhere!
Error: Host notification command 'notify-host-sms-sidd' specified for contact 'sidbiz' is not defined anywhere!
        Checked 2 contacts.
        Checked 2 contact groups.
        Checked 30 commands.
        Checked 5 time periods.
        Checked 0 host escalations.
        Checked 0 service escalations.
Checking for circular paths...
        Checked 56 hosts
        Checked 0 service dependencies
        Checked 0 host dependencies
        Checked 5 timeperiods
Checking global event handlers...
Checking obsessive compulsive processor commands...
Checking misc settings...

Total Warnings: 0
Total Errors:   4

***> One or more problems was encountered while running the pre-flight check...
[root@testing objects]#
```

Comment: Are you really using `service_notification_commands   notify-service-sms-sidd,   notify-service-email-sidd` with many spaces after comma? If it is true, try without spaces.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Rohlik. I tried the as you advised. But, still getting the same error.

Comment: Do you have `notify-host-email-sidd     // this will referd by contact.cfg` in you commands configuration? Try it without `// this will referd by contact.cfg` because it is not taken as a comment.